# cakephp: missing database table blog example

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Just started with Cake PHP. I am following the book that is provided on the official website.
For the first blog example, I did create the controller,  the model and the view, i.e. `PostsController.php` , `Post.php` and `index.ctp`.

**LearnCake\app\Controller\PostsController.php**

```
<?php

class PostsController extends AppController{
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index(){
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }
}
?>
```

**LearnCake\app\View\Posts\index.ctp**

```
<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Created</th>
</tr>
<!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $post[’Post’][’id’]; ?></td>
<td>
<?php echo $this->Html->link($post[’Post’][’title’],
array(’controller’ => ’posts’, ’action’ => ’view’, $post[’Post’][’id’])); ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $post[’Post’][’created’]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($post); ?>
</table>
```

The Model is left blank as given in the example:

**LearnCake\app\Model\Post.php**
    class Post extends AppModel {
    }

I tried to access the page with this URL `http://localhost/LearnCake/posts/index` but I am getting the error:

```
Missing Database Table

Error: Table p_o_s_ts for model Post was not found in datasource default.
```

As for the example, I did create a table called `posts`. I can't figure why is it searching for a table named `p_o_s_t`.

My Connection file is:

```
<?php

class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'cakephp',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

    public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'cakephp',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong? 
Am using `netbeans 7.2.1`. Created a project named `LearnCake`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Jimmie Lin said, the database table's name should be plural. However, it seems it's looking for a table to match a model called 'POST' (all caps).

In your controller, put `public $name = 'Posts';` or in your model, `public $name = 'Post';` to make sure it's not looking for p_o_s_ts.

And like Jimmie Lin said, make sure the table name is in plural (i.e. 'posts').

If you wanted to use a table called 'post', just add `public $useTable = 'post';` inside your model.

Comment: Any insight on why it would default to matching 'POST'? I've seen this kind of issues before, but I thought it was just too much coffee for the day.

Comment: Not sure why it could do that, hasn't ever happened to me before. First thing that comes to mind is that it could be something in your routes, or the server configuration - perhaps URL rewriting is somehow set up to match it to the 'all caps' version of the URL params. Don't know though, just an idea.

Comment: Did you get it working anyway? Edit: Sorry, thought it was the OP asking that!

Comment: @SharkofMirkwood  awesome :) and +1 to this explaination `However, it seems it's looking for a table to match a model called 'POST' (all caps).`

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a table called `posts` or `post`? The Database Table's name should be plural, but you used singular according to your question.

Comment: the table is `posts`. Edited the table name in question